# jquery late binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code that bind's on click action on page load, it is a link. When i clicking it, it send ajax request and replace content in some div with jquery append() function. This new content has a links and i need to bind some action for them, but i could't.. bind did't work i think, because jquery append doesn't update DOM tree. How could i get a late binding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Late binding is now available by utilizing jQuery's live() event:

```
$('a.my-links-class').live('click', function() {
    // do your link action here
});
```

Comment: This just made my day. live() is amazing!

Comment: You should be using `on()` instead of `live()`.

Answer (score 16):

There are 3 functions that can do this:

- `$(selector).live(events, data, handler);` - jQuery 1.3+ - *version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9* ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/live/))
- `$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);` - jQuery 1.4.3+ - *As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.* ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/))
- `$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);` - jQuery 1.7+ - preferred ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

It's **generally adviced to use `on()`** and it's use is simple and probably preferred way.

1. The first selector must exist when calling the function and may not be deleted or the event will be gone too (this can be `document`).
2. The first parameter is the event (e.g. "click")
3. The second parameter is the selector of which you want to bind the event on.
4. Then finally you can add some custom data and a function to the event.

Here's some sample code:

```
// Make sure the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    // Bind the click event to the function
    $(document).on("click", "a.class", function(event) {
        // Put your code here.
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! I am wondering why this doesn't work : 

$(function() {
    $('.class').on("click", "a", function(event) {
        // Put your code here.
    });
});

Comment: You're looking for an `a` element inside another element with class `class`?

Comment: Yea... I thought `$('.class1')` will select all elements with a class of `class1`, the `"a"` will select the anchor tags out of it, and bind the  event handler. No?

Answer (score 6):

Method `.live` in `JQuery 1.9` is deprecated.So now u can do like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".classname", function() { ... })
```

Comment: Will this add event listeners again and again on body click?

Answer (score 5):

the **.live()** event was **deprecated** from verions 1.9 up.

For anyone using later version of Jquery they can use the **.on()** event, it works pretty much in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use jQuery's [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) function, which will bind an event to all elements that match a selector, no matter when they were created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery 1.3+'s `$().live(event, function)` function. `$("a").live("click", myClickFunc)` will bind `myClickFunc` just like `$("a").click(myClickFunc)` or `$("a").bind("click", myClickFunc)`, but the events will be bound "live", so elements that are added to the DOM after that function call will also be bound.
You can remove live-bound events with `$().die()`. 
For more information on $().live, see [the documentation for it](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn).

Another option would be to have a function to bind the elements given a certain context (using the $ selector function's rarely-used second parameter):

```
function myBindEvents(context) {
     $("a", context).click(myClickFunc);
}
```

and call that whenever you update an element with AJAX:

```
$("<div>").load("...", "...", function(){myBindEvents(this);});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using js library in that I have element variable and code was like

```
$(element).click(function(){
    //some action
});
```

but that is not working with my late binding element.
So I finally use core js click event

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //My some action
}, false);
```